# How to play MPMediaItem in MPMusicPlayerController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, mpmediaquery

I am trying to play `MPMedaiItem` in `MPMusicPlayerController` in iOS.
In my case , i have a `UITableView` that show songs from playlist.
When i tap cell on `UITableView` , i want to play that song with `MPMusicPlayerController`.
And i also want to skip next songs from playlist when i tap Next Button.
How can i play it?

Here is some of my codes that write in `didSelected` Method of `UITableView`.
That doesn't play anything.

```
    MPMediaItemCollection *songs = [self.arrayOfSongs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

    MPMediaItem *item = [songs representativeItem ];

    NSLog(@"%@",[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle ]);

    [self.player setNowPlayingItem:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];

    [self.player play ];
```

Answer (score 10):

I know this is a little late, but your problem is that `MPMusicPlayerController`'s `nowPlayingItem` property expects a `MPMediaItem` object, and you're passing it an `NSString` containing the URL of the asset. Here's an example of how this could be accomplished.

```
MPMusicPlayerController *controller = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

MPMediaItemCollection *collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:arrayOfMediaItems];
MPMediaItem *item = [collection representativeItem];

[controller setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
[controller setNowPlayingItem:item];

[controller prepareToPlay];
[controller play];
```

Comment: iPodMusicPlayer is long outdated. One alternative is `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer`.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to use AVPlayer in an instance like this.

in your header file declare the AVPlayer object;

```
AVPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

Then in your method file use something like:

```
if(!audioPlayer){
   audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];
} else {
   [audioPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:itemURL]];
}
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Not sure this will work if item URL is nil (not downloaded)